# How can I center text underneath an image?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have three `h1` tags that I want to be aligned with three images. How can I do this? I want the text to be aligned under the image, but the code I have now is off by quite a bit.

```css
.column {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column>h1 {
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold';
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/7rG6nw7kN.png" alt="design">
    <h1>Design</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/7rG6nw7kN.png" alt="design">
    <h1>Code</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/7rFbByg7Y.png" alt="design">
    <h1>Collaborate</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.column {
  display: flex;             /* new (1) */
  flex-direction: column;    /* new (2) */
  align-items: center;       /* new (3) */
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column > h1 {
  /* display: flex; <--- remove; not necessary */
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold';
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/7rG6nw7kN.png" alt="design">
    <h1>Design</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/7rG6nw7kN.png" alt="design">
    <h1>Code</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/7rFbByg7Y.png" alt="design">
    <h1>Collaborate</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Notes:

1. Make parent of `img` and `h1` elements a flex container.
2. Stack flex items vertically.
3. Horizontally center flex items.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the `display: flex` on the heading.  That's partially to blame.

Instead you would want to consider:

```css
.heading {
text-align: center;
}

.heading span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="" />
  <span>Title Text</span>
</h1>
```

By placing the image within the heading, the visible text acts as the label for the image, so you don't need to add additional alt text, as it's purely there for decoration.

Answer (score 0):

Take out display:flex from h1 and style as follows

Snippet below

```css
.column {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 0 100px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.column>h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold';
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid red;
  margin-top: 0;
}

img {
  border: solid blue;
}

.column>h1 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/7rG6nw7kN.png" alt="design">
    <h1>Design</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/7rG6nw7kN.png" alt="design">
    <h1>Code</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/7rFbByg7Y.png" alt="design">
    <h1>Collaborate</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.column img{width:80%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
.column h1{text-align:center;}
```

First give the img it is width which is by percent from the column width then with margin left and right auto it will be center within your div then by giving text-align:center you will centering the text of your hedear under your image with in the column here us the idea and above is the code.

Comment: Need to add more information on what you are doing here.